# Django web page- how to manipulate what information is displayed in a table

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Django project, and one of my `views` renders a page that displays a table with information about objects in the database. The objects displayed differ based on the criteria determined in the `view`.

The `if` statement used in the `view` to determine which page to render is:

```
if request.GET.get('stage') == 'pd':        
    print "request.GET.get('stage') == 'pd' "
    print "render_to_string() called with parameter: costing/report2_ccis.html"
    context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report2_ccis.html', context)
    context['active_tab'] = '4'

    if(project.deposit_received == True):
        print "costing/reports_post_deposit.html is the page being rendered (project.deposit_received = true)... "
        context['post_deposit'] = True
        print "context['post_deposit']: ", context['post_deposit']
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_post_deposit.html', context)
    elif(project.deposit_received == False):
        print "costing/reports_pre_deposit.html is the page being rendered (project.deposit_received = False)..."
        context['post_deposit'] = False
        print "context['post_deposit']: ", context['post_deposit']
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_pre_deposit.html', context)
else:
    print "request.GET.get('stage') != 'pd' "
    print "render_to_string() called with parameter: costing/report_ccis.html"
    context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report_ccis.html', context)
    context['active_tab'] = '5'
    if(project.deposit_received == True):
        print "costing/reports_post_deposit.html is the page being rendered (project.deposit_received = true)..."
        context['post_deposit'] = True
        print "context['post_deposit']: ", context['post_deposit']
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_post_deposit.html', context)
    elif(project.deposit_received == False):
        print "costing/reports_pre_deposit.html is the page being rendered (project.deposit_received = false)..."
        context['post_deposit'] = False
        print "context['post_deposit']: ", context['post_deposit']
        return render(request, 'costing/reports_pre_deposit.html', context)
```

Both of the `templates` returned in the `view` extend another template called `reports_tabbed.html`, and the `report_ccis.html` & `report2_ccis.html` templates that are passed to the `render_to_string` view both `extends` another template called `pdf2_base.html`.

The table that's displaying the information on the webpage (whichever one is passed to `render_to_string`- `report_ccis.html` or `report2_ccis.html`) is defined in `pdf2_base.html` with:

```
<table class="pdf-report left">
    {% for payment_details in payments_details %}
        {% if forloop.first %}

        <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for detail in payment_details %}
                    <th>{{ detail.0 }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% endif %}
    <tbody>
        {% if 0 %}
            <tr class="end-table-section"></tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}


            <tr {% if forloop.last %}class="end-table-section last-row"{% endif %}>


            {% for detail in payment_details %}
                <td {% if detail.0 == 'Gross payment (£)' %}class="payment-{{detail.2}}"{% endif %}>
                {% if detail.1 and detail.0 != 'Date paid' and detail.0 != 'Date' %}
                {% if detail.0 == 'VAT (£)' or detail.0 == 'Scheduled payment (£)' or detail.0 == 'Gross payment (£)' %}
                    {{ detail.1|money }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ detail.1 }}
                {% endif %}
                {% elif detail.1 %}
                {{ detail.1|date:'d-M' }}
                {% endif %}
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            {% if 0 %}
                <tr class="end-table-section"></tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <tr class="end-table-section">
            <td>Gross payment now due:</td>
            <td>{{gross_payment_due|money:'£'}}</td>
            <td>Current contract sum</td>
            <td>Exc VAT {{ latest_total_exc|money:'£' }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Bank</td>
            <td>Handelsbanken</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Total payments made</td>
            <td>Exc VAT {{total_paid_exc|money:'£'}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td> acc</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Outstanding contract sum</td>
            <td>Exc VAT {{outstanding_exc|money:'£'}}</td>
            <td>Inc VAT {{outstanding_inc|money:'£'}}</td>
            <td>Sort Code</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="last-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">Please ensure address is put as reference</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do, is change this table in the template when it is displayed by the `if(project.deposit_received == False)` conditions in the `view`, so that one of the columns in the table ('Latest Sum') is not displayed in the table... But given that the table is generated & populated using Django `for` loops, as it changes dynamically based on the information retrieved from the database, I'm not sure how to do this...

Is there a way I can explicitly tell the code, either in the Python or the Django/ HTML not to display a certain column of the table when a particular condition is met?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can pass to the template some variable through the context and check if it was pre or post deposit.

```
if(project.deposit_received == True):
    context['post_deposit'] = True
    return render(request, 'costing/reports_post_deposit.html', context)
elif(project.deposit_received == False):
    context['post_deposit'] = False
    return render(request, 'costing/reports_pre_deposit.html', context)
```

So now yoou need to check this value in template:

```
{% if post_deposit %}
    do_something
{% else %}
    do_something_else
{% endif %}
```

And the last one you can check current iteration of cycle in template using `forloop.counter`. For example if you need to remove 3rd column in post_deposit table you can check if the loop counter equal to 3 and skip iteration:

```
{% for detail in payment_details %}
    {% if not post_deposit or forloop.counter != 3 %} 
        <th>{{ detail.0 }}</th>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update, I gave this a go- and while it has removed that column for when the `deposit_received` variable is `False`, it also removes it when the variable is `True`, so that column is now no longer displayed at all... I'm guessing there's something I need to look into with regard to the condition now- but my debug is displaying the value of this variable every time I load the page- and whether I load it with a project that sets this variable's value to `True` or `False`, the column is never displayed...

Comment: @someone2088 did you check value in template? Just add into template `{{ post_deposit }}`. This will tell you is `post_deposit` changing or not. If you see that variable is changing please edit code in your question, I will look.

Comment: I can't see any output from my template (even after adding `{{ post_deposit }}` to it, but the debug in my `view` does show that the value of `post_deposit` is changing- and regardless of whether it is True or False, the column is now no longer displayed in the table at all...

Comment: I've updated my OP to show the changes made to the `view`.

Comment: @someone2088 what about this `context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report2_ccis.html', context)` and `context['html'] = render_to_string('costing/report_ccis.html', context)`. Try to move it under `context['post_deposit'] = True` and `context['post_deposit'] = False`